# How do you select only the first row and specific column of multiple rows with the same value?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a query result that looks as follows:

```
ID    NAME    Phone
----  ----    -----
1     John    123456
2     John    125678
3     John    345678
4     Abby    456789
5     Abby    567890
```

I want to return just a single row instance of name: John, where the phone number like '12%'.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE some_condition ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`

Comment: Which one of the three?

Comment: Which dbms do you use? (LIMIT is product specific...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql has a nifty aggregate function `group_concat()` with which you can list all telephone numbers (separated by a comma) for a person by doing something like

```
SELECT name, group_concat(phone) numbers FROM tbl GROUP BY name
```

This will get you

```
name    numbers 
----    --------------------
Abby    456789,567890
John    123456,125678,345678
```

With your condition `name='John' and phone LIKE '12%'` you get

```
SELECT name, group_concat(phone) numbers FROM tbl 
WHERE name='John' and phone LIKE '12%'
GROUP BY name
```

You will get fewer results like

```
name    numbers
----    -------------
John    123456,125678
```

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMSes support Windowed Aggregate Functions, this finds the lowest phone number for each name:

```
select *
from
 (
   select ID, NAME, Phone,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME 
                         ORDER BY Phone) AS RN
   from tab
   where phone like '12%'
 ) dt 
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` solution, i.e. return a wanted row only if no other same name and 12% exists, but with a higher phone#.

```
select t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.Phone
from tablename t1
where t1.phone like '12%'
  and t1.name = 'John'
  and not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.phone like '12%'
                    and t2.name = t1.name
                    and t2.phone > t1.phone)
```

The ANSI SQL way of `LIMIT` is `FETCH FIRST`:

```
select ID, NAME, Phone
from tablename
where phone like '12%'
  and name = 'John'
fetch first 1 row only
```

(Not yet supported by that many products.)